What do I do about a sockpuppet?
My second most recent question was voted to close by a person twice in quick succession, clearly using a sock-puppet account.
They then downvoted my most recent question twice with a sock-puppet account.
How do I report and have the sockpuppeting ameliorated?
I am being harassed by a user who keeps posting on my content, they cannot seem to stop especially after I pointed it out that its unwelcome and inappropriate.

When you have suspicion about sockpuppetry and/or voting fraud, you should contact the moderators via Flag -> In need of moderator intervention under a post.
This could be done on any post. Ideally, it should be one involved in the fraudulent activity but if that is not possible for any reason (say, there are suspected sockpuppets but no clear indication where they acted) then it is acceptable to flag any of your own posts with a custom moderator flag and explain suspicions.
There is no need to cast one flag per post, if multiple posts can be identified. Try to give a link to the affected posts in the flag instead. The text field for the reason is limited to 500 characters which is often too little when trying to explain a situation. Some tricks might be to try and shorten any links
Normally the short link to a post can be grabbed from the "Share" button under a post. For example https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/37105  that is 32 characters plus what the ID would be. The link shown is 37 characters. Just four of these links consume 151 characters (including a space or a comma or other single characters separator).
However, since custom flag reasons support the same limited Markdown syntax as comments do. Thus a relative URL can be used with a markdown syntax for a link, to get shorten the full URL to [1](/a/37105) (which produces 1) this is 13 characters. Or 7 required characters + the ID + what you put as a description.

It is very important to gather evidence when you cast the flag. That is not to say that you should not do it on a hunch - some times that is all you have. However, try to find information that hints at something wrong because it is also important to validate the assumptions.

My second most recent question was voted to close by a person twice in quick succession

It is not easy to find exactly when each close vote was cast. However, there are some things that can be checked:
The timeline shows when the closure happened and who was involved. The list of close voters in the timeline is in order of voting.
The timeline also shows there was a close review for the question. Since the two people who acted with "Close" on the review also coincide with the last two users in the close voters, we can then see when they cast their close votes and the timestamps are 2024-08-23 00:02:42Z and 2024-08-23 02:19:56Z - a little more than two hours apart.
Although that accounts for 4th and 5th close vote. There is no hard data what the difference between the 3rd and 4th close vote is. The close vote review item was created at 2024-08-22 23:18:55Z (from the first timestamp in the timeline) which usually means there was a close vote or a flag which put the question in the queue. This does coincide with the comment that a user left explaining why they voted to close (timeline entry). Note that the review item creation does not necessarily match exactly to a close vote, it is usually some minutes later. So, the comment and closure probably originated at 2024-08-22 23:01:34Z.
So, from start to finish, it took about three hours to complete. If we exclude the last close vote, it took around an hour for four users to cast their close votes.
This, by itself, does not appear suspicious. Four people active in curation acting on a post close to each other is normal. Especially, since there was a comment that went with the first close vote. It is entirely plausible people had already been monitoring the post and seeing the comment pushed them into action. At any rate, it can be one piece of a puzzle.

They then downvoted my most recent question twice with a sock-puppet account.

In some ways downvotes are a flipped version of close votes. It is easier to find when they happened but impossible to say who.
In the reputation tab in the user profile of the poster we can see when exactly a downvote was cast by checking the "downvote" events (that show a -2 reputation change). Make sure to change to "Post" view to see the individual downvote events:

Although, since for "yesterday" there is only one event, you need to flip to the "Time" view to see that timestamp:

Thus we can see that the post received three downvotes around when the close votes happened:

at 2024-08-22 23:27:59Z
at 2024-08-23 00:06:08Z
at 2024-08-23 01:38:53Z

First, there are very large gaps between these events. Again, by itself, it should not suggest anything wrong - a sockpuppet can vote hours after another related vote. But it is an observation.
Second, this is still within a short enough time of the post's creation time (2024-08-22 23:20:26Z). This is usually to be expected when a question is created and users check it and vote. Again, by itself does not mean much.
A moderator can get a better idea if there is a relation between these actions.
